# How to Pass Value Form app.js to Vue File In Vue Js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

This is my app.js and it is getting value **gtotal**. I want to pass this value to my **orderForm.vue** file and I am not to do that.

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window.EventBus = new Vue();
Vue.component('products', require('./components/products.vue'));
Vue.component('orders', require('./components/orders.vue'));
Vue.component('orderform', require('./components/orderForm.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    viewOrderForm: false,
    gtotal: 0
  },
  created() {
    EventBus.$on('openOrderForm', (total) => {
        this.viewOrderForm = true;
        this.gtotal = total;
        console.log(this.gtotal);
    });
  }
});
```

In orderForm.vue, I want to assign it to the input field value so that I can save it to the Database.

```
<template>
  <input type="hidden" value="gtotal">
</template>
```

Comment: Share your live demo ?

Comment: agreed with @C2486

Comment: @C2486. I don't have a live demo but I just want to pass that gtotal value from app.js to orderForm.vue. It is showing that value in console also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've got an event bus set up, you can listen for `openOrderForm` in the component which has the order form:

```
<template>
  ...
    <order-form :gtotal="gtotal"></order-form>
  ...
</template>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      gtotal: 0
    }
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('openOrderForm',(total)=>{
      this.gtotal = total;
    })
  }
}
```

Your order form would just need a `prop` for `gtotal`:

```
// orderForm.vue

<template>
  <input type="hidden" :value="gtotal">
</template>

export default {
  props: ['gtotal']
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @DigitalDrifter. You solved my problem. Thank you very much.